# Can somebody prove that this function is continous in $f(0)$

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a function $f: \mathbb{B}^n \to [-1,1]^n$ defined as
$
f(x) = \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty}
$,
where $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, , and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$.
I comprehend the continuity of this function at other points and am attempting to establish its continuity at $x=0$. Specifically, in evaluating $\lim_{{x \to 0}} f(x)$, I obtain $\|f(x) - 0\| = \|f(x)\|=\frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty}$.  I aim to utilize the fact that $\|x\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty$. However, in this case, shouldn't I get $\frac{\|x\|_2^2 }{\|x\|_\infty}\leq \sqrt{n} \cdot {\|x\|_\infty}$ to use it? This expression tends to $0$ as
$x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: It is not continuous. $f(\frac 1 m,0,0,..)=1$ for every $m$.